# coupling coefficient & effective turn ratio

Tags: transformer

In the fundamentals-of-power-electronics this book, Chapter 13 Transformer Modeling
[image]
How to derive the coupling coefficient (13.52) & effective turn ratio (13.51)

I can use the ideal transformer to derive but non-ideal is difficult to me

[image]

[image]

Comment: I could try to deduce what you were trying to ask, but I'd rather you do it, so there will be no mistakes.

Comment: Can you work out k when the secondary is unloaded?

Comment: @Andyaka what do you mean

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen is it not clear?

Comment: I don't think I can be clearer - I'm testing you to see what baseline knowledge you have.

Comment: @Andyaka No it can't